# How add Typescript variable value to Angular div tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

How I declare a value to "x" by clicking a button in Typescript code

```
<div>
    <h3 >{{this.x}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `this` in Angular templates

Comment: Ok It's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TS file add this

```
x: any; 

changeX(){
this.x = your value;
}
```

In your HTML file add this

```
<button (click)="changeX()"></button> 

<div>
    <h3 >{{x}}</h3>
</div>
```